# In @Html.TextBoxFor(..) (et al) is it safe to use Model vs the parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I've always followed the intended convention of using the parameter for model binding in ASP.Net MVC Razor "-For(..)" helpers. I know that the parameter is the view's model (the Model property). But what are the potential side effect of binding to the Model property instead?

In other words, what are the consequences of, ..

instead of this ..

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MyProperty)
```

.. doing this instead?

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.MyProperty)
```

Comment: They are identical (its an expression)

Comment: But a word of warning about using capital `M` Model - in some circumstances you will get an error if you also have code such as `@Model.someProperty` in the view, so best avoid it